# Convert func.now() from sqlalchemy to a string

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to convert the result of func.now() from sqlalchemy to a string object? Something along the lines of

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

I want to use this result in a raw sqlalchemy that updates a datetime column in mysql. This query accepts only string parameters.

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508799/how-can-i-insert-the-value-of-current-timestamp-using-sqlalchemys-connection-ex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str(func.now())` returns `now()` which is the SQL function for using the current timestamp.  In other words, if you're constructing a raw query you can pass that in directly and MySQL will automatically fill in the current timestamp.  If you want to pass in something along the lines of `%m/%d/%Y`, then `func.now` is not the appropriate tool to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to know if you found this somewhere in the sql alchemy docs? Because I didn't find anything. How did you know applying str will produce 'now()'

Comment: I don't know if that specifically is in the docs.  But generally you can convert any sort of SQLAlchemy query or function into it's raw SQL equivalent by calling `str` on it.  That's effectively how SQLAlchemy works under the covers.

Comment: This inserts a  '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in the database. Instead of current time. It doesn't work

Comment: What's your full SQL statement?

Comment: `session.execute(text("UPDATE MoveTable A SET A.city=:city, A.move_date=:move_date"), 
                    {'city': NY, 'move_date': str(func.now())})
 session.commit()`

Comment: You're not actually calling the `NOW()` function in the SQL.  It's effectively attempting to convert the literal `"now()"` to a datetime.  Just do `text("UPDATE MoveTable A SET A.city=:city, A.move_date=NOW()")`

Comment: Ya. I figured that out. Thanks.